# ROR (MVC): Where to put this code? write function in model or write 2 script in controller and service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have ruby on rails application, the app have 1 module which have table temp_ms and ms. table temp_ms used to store temp data, if that temp data is approved, then the data will move from temp_ms to ms. Before user approve, there's one dropdown which contain option "yes" and "no". If user select "yes", then when the data get approved, script for "copy data from temp_ms to ms" will get executed immediately. Buf if user select "no", script for "copy data from temp_ms to ms" will be executed on a later date using cronjob.

(Let's call script for "copy data from temp_ms to ms" as script A)

These 2 option will execute the same script A, what I want to know is, which is the better option (with considering MVC concept), do I write 2 script ? one in approve method controller, one in service which will be called by cronjob? Or I write 1 function in model ms, then the function will be called in controller and service?

Note: Script A contain create and update data from many table (at least 400 line) (table example: temp_ms, temp_ms_a, temp_ms_b, ms, ms_a, ms_b) (I don't know if this script is called as bussiness logic or domain logic)

Comment: Did you mean to write model in "the app have 1 module"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would create a service object in somewhere like `app/actions/copy_data_from_temp_ms_to_ms.rb` which handles all of the logic for migrating the data for you.

Then:

- in your controller, you can call that service object to do the work if they select `Yes`
- in your cronjob/whatever which runs does the migration later if they select `No`, you also call the same service object to do the work

This way, you can do the migration from both places, without duplicating your logic.

I don't believe this belongs in the model.

There are a lot of articles online about service objects that can help you:

- https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/06/17/using-service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails.html
- https://medium.com/selleo/essential-rubyonrails-patterns-part-1-service-objects-1af9f9573ca1
- https://blog.engineyard.com/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services
- https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/09/rails-patterns-presenter-service/